# Any significance for the number 2295 in the "Chicago" franchise?

Tags: chicago-pd, chicago-med, chicago-fire

In almost every (if not all) scenes where the camera follows a character in or out of a taxi, it's the same taxi with the number 2295.

This is consistent in all of the shows in the *Chicago* franchise (*Med*, *Fire* and *PD*) and can't be a coincidence.

Comment: Maybe that's the fake Taxi car the studio owns?